# How to read variables values after execute a SSIS package in the Calalog?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014

I am trying to execute a SSIS package from a store procedure, and I want to get the value of a variable defined in the SSIS package. I can execute tha package but I do not know how to get the value of the variable after the executtion

I am executing the package in this way:

```
-- Create the execution object
DECLARE @execution_id BIGINT
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] 
    @package_name=N'package.dtsx'
    , @project_name=N'my_project'
    , @folder_name=N'packages'
    , @use32bitruntime=False
    , @reference_id=NULL
    , @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT

-- System parameters
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
    @execution_id
    , @object_type = 50                     -- System parameter
    , @parameter_name = N'SYNCHRONIZED'
    , @parameter_value = 1

DECLARE @PATH AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @PATH='c:\results\test.xlsx'

EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_property_override_value] 
  @execution_id = @execution_id,
  @property_path = '\package.Variables[User::FILE_PATH].Properties[Value]',
  @property_value = @PATH,
  @sensitive = 0; 

-- Execute the package
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id

-- Check package status, and fail script if the package failed
IF 7 <> (SELECT [status] FROM [SSISDB].[catalog].[executions] WHERE execution_id = @execution_id)
RAISERROR('The package failed. Check the SSIS catalog logs for more information', 16, 1)
```

My package writes a value to a variable called ID, and I need to get the value. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The values of the variables are encapsulated within the package. If you want to get their values you'll need to implement your own logging process(es).

Comment: Hi @Larnu. What do you mean with "implement your own process"?  I set RaiseChangedEvent=True on the variable, but I think it is useless.

Comment: RaiseChangedEvent is pretty useless from what I've been able to tell. It doesn't tell you old/new values, just that it's a new state. And expressions don't cause the event to fire. That said, your package runs and at the end @[User::ID] has some value in it. How do you want to use it outside the process? Lazy approach would be to fire an [information event](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2016/04/biml-script-task-test-for-echo.html) in a script task and then parse the resulting value out of ssisdb.catalog.operation_messages

Comment: Or you could create a custom table, my_package_runlog and associate an execution/operation id (bigint) with the ID which you'd populate via an Execute SQL Task before the package completes execution

Comment: Hi @billinkc, if I use a custom table, how can I know the execution_id inside  the package to associate with my variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a thing I need to work with regularly, I'd create a custom table. Something like this

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PackageRunLog
(
    PackageControlSK int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL 
,   PackageName varchar(100) NOT NULL
,   PackageID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
,   ExecutionID bigint NULL
,   MyCustomVariable int
};
```

As the final step of your package, have an Execute SQL Task that makes an insert into the table.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.PackageRunLog VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);
```

In the Parameter section, use the following SSIS variables

- System::PackageName
- System::PackageID
- System::ServerExecutionID
- User::MyVariable

The first two record the package friendly name and the second is the internal guid associated to your package. This can be helpful in case someone has a generic named package LoadData which matches your package LoadData. Or if package names change, whatever.

The magic is System::ServerExecutionID This value *is* the execution_id/operation_id recorded in SSISDB.catalog.operations, catalog.operation_messages etc

Finally, we map our SSIS variable MyVariable into it.

My actual run log has start/stop dates, insert/update/delete counts but that's the general pattern.

My Lazy approach would be to fire an information event in a script task and then parse the resulting value out of ssisdb.catalog.operation_messages

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation!